# Android AudioGroup device loop timeout

Tags: android, speech-recognition, sip

I'm trying to develop an Android Native SIP VoIP App. For the SIP session instantiation I use the example Code, provided bei Google (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html). In my testing environment, I call a second phone with CSipSimple VoIP application from my own VoIP app. Making a call works fine, until I parallel launch the speechrecognition from android to transcript the spoken words. On the phone with my own VoIP app, the sound has great quality. On the second phone, using CSipSimple, only returns a kind of noise and

```
 02-19 20:09:02.844: W/AudioGroup(15906): device loop timeout
```

errors. Does anyone know, how to simultaneously set up a SIPAudioCall and SpeechRecognition?
Thank you very much in advance!
Nicolai